# Configuring actual php version and ini file

Tags: php, apache, xampp, wamp

I don't understand how PHP or Apache work or are installed. I thought that if I install WAMP or XAMP the Apache or the PHP used have to be the one I executed. If I execute XAMP, Apache, PHP, and MySQL have to be XAMP installed versions. But this doesn't seem to be the case.

Some time ago I installed WAMP (PHP 5.4). Recently I installed XAMP too and began using it (PHP 5.5). Now I'm installing xdebug and executing `php --ini` and I get this result:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => C:\WINDOWS
Loaded Configuration File => D:\Webs\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\php.ini
```

Can anybody tell me how this works and how to select the XAMP or the WAMP version?

Do I have to install xdebug in my WAMP path instead of my XAMP path?

Comment: From where are you executing `php --ini` and have you made the untimate mistake of adding either WAMPServer or XAMPP directories to the PATH environmant variable in windows. Remember thay both provide you basically the same things and unless you know what you are doing they will get in the way of each other

Comment: Thanks RiggsFolly, the problem are PATHS that this utilities make. (Sure it was a mistake, I have MAMP too :P) I'll uninstall them. (Thanks too to code editors, I apologize for my English)